# Wrap around continuous colormap in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working with some 2-dimensional phase data and am trying to plot it in a reasonable way.  With phase, 358 degrees and 2 degrees are very close, but when plotting, colorbars tend to show them as being maximally different. This is unacceptable.

The code below is a hack which I borrowed from [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/10/16/how-bad-is-your-colormap/) that sort of does what I want, but only in grayscale, and it's rather ugly.

I do not want to modify my data to do this (eg, `phase = np.abs(phase-180)`). How can I make a continuous *color* map that starts at 0 with some color, then ends at 360 with the same color?  I would prefer a solution not requiring extra packages.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



def grayify_cmap(cmap):
    """Return a grayscale version of the colormap"""
    cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap(cmap)
    colors = cmap(np.arange(cmap.N))
    # convert RGBA to perceived greyscale luminance
    # cf. http://alienryderflex.com/hsp.html
    RGB_weight = [0.299, 0.587, 0.114]
    luminance = np.sqrt(np.dot(colors[:, :3] ** 2, RGB_weight))
    colors[:, :3] = luminance[:, np.newaxis]
    return cmap.from_list(cmap.name + "_grayscale", colors, cmap.N)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    xdata = np.arange(100)
    ydata = xdata.copy()

    X, Y = np.meshgrid(xdata, ydata)
    phase = 1.80*(X+Y)


    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(phase)
    plt.title('Unacceptable colormap')
    plt.colorbar()

    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(phase, cmap=grayify_cmap('RdGy'))
    plt.title('Barely acceptable ugly colormap')
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for that.  I might end up doing that, but I'll edit my question to prefer not using extra packages.

Comment: If you don't want extra packages just use `matplotlib.pyplot.get_cmap('hsl')`.

Comment: 'hsl' is not a valid colormap in matplotlib

Comment: `hsv` is a cyclic colormap that is available in matplotlib http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html

Comment: I assume you've been here, but if you look at the grayscale representations of `matplotlib`s native color maps, you can work out which look cyclic. See http://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html#grayscale-conversion.  Some are pretty ugly in colour, but cyclic in grayscale (e.g. 'jet')

Comment: Yes, I looked into that.  The 'RdGy' shown in the code above is a close approximation to cyclic when converted to grayscale.

Comment: I've just thought - the other thing is that you can define your own colour scheme so that it truly is cyclic.  If, for instance, you're happy for phase = 300 to have the same colour as phase = 60 (i.e. if you view +/-60 as the same and you want to colour based on |phase|).  If that's what you want to do, my voting for this as duplicate was perhaps in haste and I could potentially vote to reopen and add an answer based on this http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_cmap.html. Let me know .